# Does $\mathrm{span}\{u, u-v\}$ contain the vector $v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Am I thinking about this correctly?

\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{span}\{u,u-v\} &=  c_1u+c_2(u-v)\\ &= c_1u + c_2u - c_2v \\ &= c_1u + c_2u + c_3v
\end{aligned}
where $c_3=-c_2$. So we have  $$\mathrm{span}\{u,u-v\}=(c_1+c_2)u + c_3v$$ which is just $\mathrm{span}\{u,v\}$ isn't it?  Am I making a huge conceptual mistake here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\vec v= -(\vec u-\vec v)+\vec u$.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct.

However you notation is sloppy, we have
$$
\text{span}(v,v-u) = \{ c_1 v + c_2 (v-u) |\text{ for arbitrary } c_1, c_2 \}
$$
and we do not have
$$
\text{span}(v,v-u) =  c_1 v + c_2 (v-u) 
$$
the LHS is a vector space whereas the RHS is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$v=u-(u-v). $$ So $v $ is a linear combination of $u $ and $u-v $.